# Syntax to use when entering geographic data into geography columns via SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: qgis, sql-server

I am starting to learn about spatially aware databases.  I have QGIS 2.61 and SQL Server Express 2012.  I can set up a table using the  SQL Server Management studio GUI and insert a geography column.  What syntax should I use when entering data into that column to store, for instance, the coordinates for a polygon or linestring etc.  Try as I might I cannot find an answer other than using Transact SQL which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lat long point locations in a sql table and you've added a geometry field you can convert ths Lat Long to geometry with this code:

```
UPDATE tablename 
 Set geographyfield = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + 
 CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + CAST([Latitude] AS 
 VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
```

It's much more complicated with polygons and line strings and best to use other software to write the layers to sql tables. You can also use ogr and python if you have shape files or other formats and want to store them in sql server

Comment: I see my answer was in t-SQL which isn't what you want. I guess I'm not clear what you are trying to do. Enter coordinate data in QGIS? Build a geometry field with coordinates in SQL?